# Function passed as parameter to custom hooks is not taking new value of variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I use below custom hook for listening to window unload event.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useUnload = fn => {
    
    const cb = useRef(fn); // init with fn, so that type checkers won't assume that current might be undefined

    useEffect(() => {
        cb.current = fn;
    }, [fn]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onUnload = cb.current;

        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
    }, []);
};

export default useUnload;
```

When the unload function is called, the variable are of the values when the hook is initialized. The updated values of variables are not reflected.

```
  useUnload(e => {
        console.log(variableA) //It is retaining the old value when the hook is initialized.
      
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = ""
       
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function will be used because you are dereferencing the `current` property of the `cb` ref directly in the effect, which only happens once after the initial render of the component that uses the `useUnload` hook.

You can create a new function in the effect that in turn dereferences the `current` property of the `cb` ref when it is called and the latest function will be used.

```
const useUnload = fn => {
    const cb = useRef(fn); // init with fn, so that type checkers won't assume that current might be undefined

    useEffect(() => {
        cb.current = fn;
    }, [fn]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onUnload = () => {
            cb.current();
        };

        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
    }, []);
};
```